# Creating a concrete constructor for a generic class without inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Is it possible to offer constructors for a generic class that would make the class non generic without inheritance?

```
namespace MathParser.Calculation
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;

    class Stackoverflow<T>
    {
        private Func<IConvertible, IFormatProvider, T> convertValue;
        private Func<T, T, T> op;

        public Stackoverflow(Func<IConvertible, IFormatProvider, T> ToGenericValue, Func<T, T, T> opGeneric)
        {
            this.convertValue = ToGenericValue;
            this.op = opGeneric;
        }

        /* This is what i want to write
        public Stackoverflow(Func<Int64, Int64, Int64> opGeneric) where T : Int64
        {
            this.convertValue = (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); };
            this.op = opGeneric;
        }
        */

        public T operation<K>(K a, K b) where K : IConvertible
        {
            T aAsT = this.convertValue(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            T bAsT = this.convertValue(b, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return op(aAsT, bAsT);
        }
    }

    class Caller
    {
        public void call(Int64 a, Int64 b)
        {
            var op1 = new Operation<Int64>(
                (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); }, //repeated
                (x, y) => { return x / y; }
                );

            var op2 = new Operation<Int64>(
                (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); }, //repeated
                (x, y) => { return x + y; }
                );

            var op3 = new Operation<Int64>(
                (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); }, //repeated
                (x, y) => { return (x - y) * x; }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously i could just inherit from the baseclass like this:

```
    class STO64 : Stackoverflow<Int64>
    {
        public STO64( Func<Int64, Int64, Int64> opGeneric)
            : base( (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); }, opGeneric )
        {
        }

        public Int64 operation<K>(K a, K b) where K : IConvertible
        {
            return base.operation(a, b);
        }
    }
```

But i was wondering it there was a way to overload the baseclass constructor with different versions.

Comment: Not possible. Why make it generic in the first place?

Comment: Well this is just an example. The real world example involves existing code and refactoring. It may well be the case that i will get rid of the generics in the future.

Comment: This is confusing. Where does inheritance come into the picture? `var so = new StackOverflow(new Func<IConvertible, IFormatProvider, Int64>(toGenericFunc), new Func<Int64, Int64, Int64>(opGenericFunc))`

Comment: Now I understand, it is not about the generics; it is about the repeated code. In that case, the derived class that you have here is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Constructor construct class it is defined in. The same class can't be generic and non-generic at the same time.

Depending on your needs you may try to add non-generic base class ( `class Base<T> : Base`) if you must avoid generic or have non-generic class with generic "creator" method `Base Create<T>()...`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is some casting.  I wrote a constructor on StackOverflow that looks like this:

```
    public Stackoverflow(Func<T, T, T> opGeneric) 
    {
        this.convertValue = (val, f) => { return (T)(IConvertible)val.ToInt64(f); };
        this.op = opGeneric;
    }
```

And then for the Caller class it looks like this (in part):

```
class Caller
{
    Stackoverflow<Int64> op1 = new Stackoverflow<Int64>(
     (x, y) => { return x / y; }
     );

 ...
}
```

In my main program, I could create a new caller with this:

```
        var caller = new Caller();
```

I also made some other changes to your project so I could execute the code.  The full solution is at
https://github.com/kc1073/Samples

KC

Comment: The question is how to make the class non-generic, isn't it? If the class is non-generic, where does your `T` come from?

Comment: Oops.  My bad.  Need to post the "call" class too.  Sorry

Comment: This is an interesting approach but i would run into trouble since another casting case is `Double` and that constructor would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes more towards your intent, rather than your stated question.

You want to set up the converters once for a specific type and then keep using them without having to specify them again each time.

Generic static variables can solve this for you.  A generic static variable is a different static variable for each variation of a generic parameter, so if we make convertValue a static variable inside of the generic type `Stackoverflow<T>`, then it `Stackoverflow<Int64>.convertValue` is a different value from `Stackoverflow<Int32>.convertValue`.  Since it is a static variable, the value will persist until the AppDomain stops running.

I converted your class to a static class with static methods and variables to demonstrate this concept.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Stackoverflow<T>
{
    private static Func<IConvertible, IFormatProvider, T> convertValue = (a, b) =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Initialize must be called to initialize the operations");
    };

    private static Func<T, T, T> op = (a, b) =>
        {
            throw new Exception("Initialize must be called to initialize the operations");
        };

    public static void Initialize(Func<IConvertible, IFormatProvider, T> ToGenericValue, Func<T, T, T> opGeneric)
    {
        convertValue = ToGenericValue;
        op = opGeneric;
    }

    public static T Operation<K>(K a, K b) where K : IConvertible
    {
        T aAsT = convertValue(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        T bAsT = convertValue(b, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return op(aAsT, bAsT);
    }
}
```

The code can be referenced as follows:

```
Stackoverflow<Int64>.Initialize(
        (val, f) => { return val.ToInt64(f); },
        (x, y) => { return x / y; }
    );

var op1 = Stackoverflow<Int64>.Operation(a, b);
var op2 = Stackoverflow<Int64>.Operation("8830000", "922");
```